# hibernate many to one foreign key not working

Tags: java, hibernate

the follwing is my hibernate example for one to many relationship

```
cart java class
@Entity
@Table(name="cart")
public class Solocart {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="carts_id")
    int id;
    @Column(name="cust_name")

    String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cartitem")
    Set<Soloitems>soloitem;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Set<Soloitems> getSoloitem() {
        return soloitem;
    }
    public void setSoloitem(Set<Soloitems> soloitem) {
        this.soloitem = soloitem;
    }




}
```

next items java file

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cartitem")
public class Soloitems {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="cart_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="no_item")
    private int number;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="carts_id")
    private Solocart cartitem;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public Solocart getCartitem() {
        return cartitem;
    }
    public void setCartitem(Solocart cartitem) {
        this.cartitem = cartitem;
    }
```

impl code

```
Session sn=Util.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    sn.beginTransaction();
    Solocart crt=new Solocart();
    crt.setName("solomon");
    Soloitems itm1=new Soloitems();
    Soloitems itm2=new Soloitems();
    itm1.setNumber(5);
    itm2.setNumber(8);
    Set<Soloitems>values= new HashSet<Soloitems>();
    values.add(itm1);
    values.add(itm2);
    crt.setSoloitem(values);
    sn.save(crt);
    sn.save(itm2);
    sn.save(itm1);
    sn.getTransaction().commit();
    sn.close();
    System.out.println("sucessfully created");
```

here one cart should have many items while running both the tanles were updated but

```
# cart_id, no_item, carts_id
     '1', '   8',     NULL
      '2', '  5',     NULL
```

second table

```
# carts_id, cust_name
    '1', '   solomon'
```

as you see both the tables has been updated but the foreignkey herein this case carts_id didnt get updated in the owner class i have used joincolumn

Comment: You need to set a Cascade option - that is, when persist parent entity - children also will be persisted. :) Also usually from @ OneToMany you should set cascades and fetches, and from @ ManyToOne use mappedBy (but it is not mandatory to use the latter one)

Comment: tahnks for the help it worked

Comment: @energizer it jsut craetesa new table cart_cartitem joining  both the tables primary key column still foreign key is not updated here is the changes u suggested

Comment: @energizer @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 
 @JoinColumn(name="carts_id") but i got a new table # cart_carts_id, soloitem_cart_id
'1',               '1'
'1',                '2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bi-directional relationship between entities `Solocart` and `Soloitems` so in your code you need to maintain the relationship from both sides of entities.

So based on this, in your code you are just setting the Soloitems to Solocart but you missed to set the Solocart to Soloitems, so as mentioned by Predrag add below lines of code to maintain the relationship:

```
itm1.setCartitem(crt);
itm2.setCartitem(crt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting `Solocart` anywhere to your `Soloitem`s. Try adding this to your code

```
itm1.setCartitem(crt);
itm2.setCartitem(crt);
```